# Filter Data In FlatList React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, filter

I have a FlatList with data which should respond to changes in two components: search bar and Category Picker. I can only use one of them at a time and filter using either only search bar or category picker.

How to filter data, for example, when I chose a category and started typing a name (eg: choose "massage" and type "John" - should show nothing, choose "massage" and type "j" - should show Jason)

Components:

```
     <View style={styles.container}>
        <DropDownPicker
            placeholder="All"
            defaultValue={categories[0].label}
            items={filteredCategories}
            onChangeItem={(item) => {
                setFilter(item.value);
                setCategories(item.value);
            }}
        />
        <TextInput
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            clearTextOnFocus={true}
            style={styles here}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
                setSearchText(text);
            }}
            value={searchText}
        />
        <FlatList
            data={filteredData}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
    </View>
```

States and Filters:

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState("all");
const [categories, setCategories] = useState("all");
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState();

//inital data
const data = [
    {
        id: "1",
        category: "massage",
        title: "Jason Bourne",
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        category: "massage",
        title: "Will Mohaw",
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        category: "stylist",
        title: "John Smith",
    },
];

//initial categories
const categoryData = [
    {
        label: "All",
        value: "all",
    },
    {
        label: "Massage",
        value: "massage",
    },
    {
        label: "Stylist",
        value: "stylist",
    },
];

//every single specialist
const Item = ({ title }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
);

//rendering each specialist
const renderItem = ({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />;

//sorting either by search or by category, below
const filteredData = searchText
    ? data.filter((x) =>
            x.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
      )
    : data;

//filter data in flatlist by category
/*const filteredData =
    filter != "all"
        ? data.filter((x) =>
                x.category.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
          )
        : data;*/
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue if you just apply the category filter on data after applying the search filter? I mean you could probably optimise it by reversing the filter orders and using a memo/callback hook since the calculation is expensive, but nonetheless the filter should be outputting the correct data that way.

Comment: The last comment was exceeding the character limit if I included codes. What I meant is:

const searchFilteredData = searchText
    ? data.filter((x) =>
            x.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
      )
    : data;

const filteredData =
    filter !== "all"
        ? searchFilteredData.filter((x) =>
                x.category.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
          )
        : searchFilteredData;

Also, you should use filter !== "all" instead of filter != "all".

Comment: Ah yes, I see my mistake. thank you! Works perfectly!